# Php results not showinf after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've To create this webpage for property dealing. I'm Using ajax to display the results int  the same page..The user is able to give input and but the results are not showing... no error message too.. plz help...I'm new to Ajax and PHP.

The html code is :

```
Enter City :<input class="w-input" id="city"   type="text" placeholder="Enter the city name (required)" name="city" data-name="city" required="required" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<div id="txtHint"><b>Results will be displayed Here...</b></div>
```

ajax code :

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","buyresult.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>
```

the final buyresult.php file content

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form/style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 include 'connection.php';
 SESSION_START();
 $q = intval($_GET['q']);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM property WHERE city = '".$q."'";
 $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while($result=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
 {
    echo '<h2 class="flat-heading">FLAT Id = '.$result['id'];
 }
 ?>
 </body>
```

Comment: if you use $q = intval($_GET['q']); it means $q is int type so your query will be $sql="SELECT * FROM property WHERE city = $q"; no need to write $q in double quote

Comment: but one more problem.. this ajax call uses only one value.. suppose we want to add more filter like location and then filter the previous result.. how to do it??.. can creating view in the first ajax call and then working on that view in second ajax call help it..?? or is there any other option.. The answer i googled is out of my understanding.. I wish you can help..

Comment: @TusharAnand its very simple you can simple add more parameter in ajax calls like this: `xmlhttp.open("GET","buyresult.php?q="+str,true);` should be now: `xmlhttp.open("GET","buyresult.php?q="+str+"&location="+loc+"&newfilter="+filt,true);`

Comment: you should move session_start to the top of the page, otherwise no cookie will be set after you output that html.

Comment: @Testing I meant that after the result of first ajax call was done.. I want to have more optional filter from the next text box in html code... to further narrow down my result to particular location on the same page..  is it possible.. how to do this ? i mean this.value will be applicable for  only one text box (city).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <script>
function showUser(str) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           // document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","buyresult.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

i think the problem is in

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
```

this part.. you might not have defined any where this id ...
and instead of getting

```
 $q = intval($_GET['q']);
```

use

```
 $q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);
```

Comment: where OP will have results of ajax in your code? Response div?

Comment: best would be if you post the code it should seems working for him since he is new in PHP and Ajax. He will copy paste your code and would not have response in div. You can see.

Comment: ya i can see will remember in future ... thanx 4 advice

Comment: you should not proposing inserting raw get data. This intval was at least sanitizing, if you propose to drop it, suggest another way, like mysql_real_escape_string, unless you plan to hack OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `buyresult.php` code should be something like this:

Your main problem is you are using `$q = intval($_GET['q']);` and adding `""` in your query So problem is in your query. Please give a go to below one. It should work for you.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form/style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 include 'connection.php';
 SESSION_START();
 $q   = intval($_GET['q']);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE city = $q";
 $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while($result=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
 {
    echo '<h2 class="flat-heading">FLAT Id = '.$result['id'];
 }
 ?>
 </body>
```